# iOS wait for server data to alter UITableView appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I am having a very hard time doing something that seems very simple in web programming.  When the iOS program starts, I run a function to gather some information from my server.  During that time there is a UITableView that loads with some initial data.  About 1 second later I get my response from the server.  Depending on that response I want to either do nothing, or grey out/disable one of the rows in the UITableView.

Using the debugging tools I can confirm that my server request is working, but for the life of my I can't figure out how to alter the cells in the UITableView.

The idea is that, say if the server responds: `true`, then I want to find the first row in the UITableView, turn the text color light grey and disable touching it.  What is the best way to do this?

I have tried many things, and I don't want to junk up this question with code examples that may be way off target. I can do what I want to do during the initial load of the UITableView (using the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method), but at that time I still don't have data from the server.  SO the hard part for me is that I need to be able to make these changes to the table at some time after initial loading, whenever the server responds.  Keep in mind that I don't want to change any content of the `dataSource`, I just want to change the appearance/functionality of 1 of the rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try setting the `allowsSelection` attribute of the `UITableViewCell` to `NO` to disable the cell (avoid reacting to taps). Then when data is fetched, call `reloadData` on your `UITableView`. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should set `allowsSelection` depending on you having the data or not. `reloadData` is fast, so your user won't notice it.

Comment: In other words: The `reloadData` method on your `UITableView` will ask your `dataSource` for the info again and update the view accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an extra variable in your UITableViewController:

```
var yourVar : Bool = false
```

Then after you have received the data from the server set the variable to either true or false and call reloadData():

```
self.yourVar = true // or self.yourVar = false 
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function have a check for the first row to change it appearance:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && yourVar == true) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
}
```

And have the method [willSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:) make sure that you cannot select that cell anymore:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
   return (indexPath.row == 0 && self.yourVar = true) ? nil : indexPath
}
```

-- Edit --

Alternatively you can check the selection property of a cell in the willSelectRowAtIndexPath using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    return (cell.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) ? nil : indexPath
}
```